# XML schema for Eclipse target definition files

Tags: eclipse, pde, buckminster

Where can I find the XML schema and/or documentation for Eclipse target definition files (*.target)?

Comment: Any clues?Not finding any where..Waiting for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no schema or documentation defining the structure of a target definition file (.target).  This is because the file structure is not intended to be API (it may change between release).

The structure has changed several times already.  The code used to serialize/deserialize the file can be found in the following classes:

```
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetDefinitionPersistenceHelper
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetPersistence38Helper
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetPersistence36Helper
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetPersistence35Helper
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetPersistence34Helper
```

Answer (score 1):

May be **[this schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/eclipse.pde.ui/8c75b9cf2bcb4a0ba7827c53423c9f9503ecbd78/ui/org.eclipse.pde.core/schema/targets.exsd)** might fit the [target files created for an RCP platform](https://web.archive.org/web/20221002152827/https://www.modumind.com/2009/09/01/creating-an-eclipse-rcp-target-platform/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [modumind.com](https://www.modumind.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/new-target-definition.png))</sub>

Part of that schema file is visible in the [Eclipse help page](https://www.eclipse.org/documentation/).

Comment: Quote from the help page: "The file format is not API and subject to change between releases." Oh, well.

Comment: That schema defines the extension point used to contribute target definitions. I can't see any definition on the contents of the *.target file itself.

Comment: that link to the schema is dead now.

Comment: @sal Thank you. I have restored the link.